# Model is Empty on HTTP POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveProduct(string id, AddProductViewModel m)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (ComparisonDBDataContext CMP = new ComparisonDBDataContext())
        {
            tblProduct prod = (from c in CMP.tblProducts
                               where c.ProductID == Guid.Parse(id)
                               select c).SingleOrDefault();
            prod.Name = m.myName;
            prod.CategoryID = Guid.Parse(m.myCategory);
            prod.ManufacturerID=Guid.Parse(m.myManufacturer);
            CMP.SubmitChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Products");
    }
    else
    {
        m.ProductID = Guid.Parse(id);
        return View("EditProduct", m);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model Comparison.Models.AddProductViewModel 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditProduct";
    Layout = "~/Views/_LayoutData.cshtml";
}

<style>
    .field-validation-error {
        color: Black;
    }
    .validation-summary-errors {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: Black;
    }
</style>
<h2>Edit Product</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProduct", "Home", new { id = @Model.ProductID }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblName">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.myName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblCategory">Category</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.myCategory,  Model.Category, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.myCategory)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" id="lblManufucturer">Manufucturer</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.myManufacturer, Model.Manufacturer, new {@class="form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.myManufacturer)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Products")
</div>
```

View Model

```
public Guid? myUserID;

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
        public string myCategory;
        public List<SelectListItem> category = new List<SelectListItem>();
        public List<SelectListItem> Category
        {
            get
            {

                category.Clear();
                using (ComparisonDBDataContext CMP = new ComparisonDBDataContext())
                {
                    var cat = from g in CMP.tblCategories
                              select new { g.Name, g.CategoryID };
                    foreach (var q in cat)
                    {
                        category.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = q.Name, Value = q.CategoryID.ToString() });
                    }
                    return category;
                }
            }
        }
        public Guid? ProductID;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public string myManufacturer;
        public List<SelectListItem> manufacturer = new List<SelectListItem>();
        public List<SelectListItem> Manufacturer
        {
            get
            {

                category.Clear();
                using (ComparisonDBDataContext CMP = new ComparisonDBDataContext())
                {
                    var manu = from g in CMP.tblManufacturers
                              select new { g.Name, g.ManufacturerID };
                    foreach (var q in manu)
                    {
                        manufacturer.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = q.Name, Value = q.ManufacturerID.ToString() });
                    }
                    return manufacturer;
                }
            }
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Maximum lenght can be 100")]
        public string myName;

        public DateTime? CreationDate;
```

I have tried googling it but could not find any solutions.

I know similar questions are already asked but i couldn't find my solution in them. So kindly just review my code and tell me what I am doing wrong. Why my Model is empty ON POSTBACK?

Comment: Can you provide viewmodel also?

Comment: Try removing the HTML attribute from `BeginForm` and take a `HiddenFieldFor` for your ProductID field.

Comment: Is `m` null or just the properties of the model?

Comment: Properties of the model are null

Comment: You don't have getter/setters on your properties (actually they are fields) so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** them. And don't put database access code in a view model (it should only contain simple properties with a `get; set;` - the controller is responsible for setting them)

Comment: Yes Sir Fixed it ... You are rite :) Properly answer the question so that i can TICK it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view model contains properties with only getters (and in some case they are just fields without any getter or setter) so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** their values. It needs to be

```
public string myName { get; set; }
```

Side note: A view model should not contain database access code. It shouldbe simply

```
public List<SelectListItem> manufacturer { get; set; }
```

and the controller should be responsible for assigning the collection to the property.